# Access Server through proxy

Tags: proxy, routes, ip, server

So I'm having a peculiar issue. I'm hosting a server at home, and as long as I'm connected to the same network when I use the external URL or IP address (www.mywebsite.com or 99.99.99.999), the page will load. If I am not connected to the same network and I use the same external URL or IP address, then it refuses to load. I get the same result by being on the network at home and using a proxy server.

Here is the kick. When I do a traceroute, am on the home network, and use the external URL or IP address, it seems to use similar routes as if I use the proxy first! (The first few steps are different, but it always ends up routing through the same ISP.)

I'm sure that I'm not the first to deal with this. If you PM me, I'll give you the actual site and IP for testing.

Thanks for the help!

- Zokah

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have enabled external access on the NAT (or router) for that port.

Comment: Thank you, Álvaro.

I actually had a couple of steps to take. 

1) I had previously set my Modem to "Router" mode, and so I changed it to just bridge the connection. 

2) I changed my router's settings to be the front-facing device.

Your advice pointed me in exactly the right direction! 

Thank you.